# I am not getting presize answer when taking 5 root (c++)

Tags: c++

The answer is off by `2.84217e-014` when trying to rake 5 root of a big number

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h> 
using namespace std;   

int main(){
    //144^5 = 61917364224
    cout << fmod(pow(61917364224, 1/5.0), 1) << endl; // 2.84217e-014
}
```

Comment: Floating-point numbers are not infinitely precise, it is expected that round-off errors occur.

Comment: "The answer is off by 2.84217e-014 when trying to rake 5 root of a big number" which ain't bad really. That's off on the order of centimetres on the distance from here to Neptune. If you want to do better than that then use a multiprecision library.

Comment: probably an x-y problem. OP, why are you needing the 5th root of an integer value? Are you trying to solve a problem on integers? Then floating point is not the right tool

Comment: `pow(x,y)` is typically computed as `exp(y*log(x)`, with some precision enhancements (see for instance in [glibc](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_pow.c)). It's not an exact computation.

Comment: If you need a integer-only solution for calculating roots this can easily be done: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Yscos3

Comment: @SimonKraemer Incrementing by one at each step if vastly suboptimal. For instance there is a well known algorithm for integer square root that first computes the higest bit, then all subsequent bits, one per loop. There is also Newton's method.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut the compiler does a pretty good job optimizing the code (constexpr FTW).
It wasn't meant to show a perfect solution, just that there are other methods available.